# Not able to Deploy my decentralized web app onto the Dfinity ICP network

Tags: javascript, decentralized-applications, motoko, dfinity

[Output of the error generated while trying to deploy my webapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4MJW.png)

I was trying to deploy my webapp on the Internet Protocol Network ICP  using the following command dfx deploy --network ic  but encounterd the following errors

> Uploading assets to asset canister...
> Error: Failed while trying to deploy canisters.
> Caused by: Failed while trying to deploy canisters.
> Failed while trying to install all canisters.
> Failed to install wasm module to canister 'dbank_assets'.
> Failed to store assets in canister 'dbank_assets'.
> Failed asset sync with canister sf263-2iaaa-aaaak-qceca-cai.
> Asset with key '/logo.png' defined at /home/gaurav472/dbank/dist/dbank_assets/logo.png and /home/gaurav472/dbank/src/dbank_assets/assets/logo.png

I have tried everything but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a missing logo asset or the path does not exist